# Accidentally Working on the Wrong Named Branch in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have been making some changes to my working directory, and noticed that I have accidentally been working on the wrong branch. I have not committed anything yet, and I would like my next commit to go against another branch. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Shelve extension can give you grief, and this can be done entirely with Mercurial commands.  Krtek almost had it but he used `export` instead of `diff`.  Try this:

```
hg diff --git > ~/saved-work.patch
hg update --clean desiredbranch
hg import --no-commit ~/saved-work.patch
```

Comment: Yes, `hg selve`, patch-queues et al. are not working and give you indeed grief! This solution above is indeed a good practice.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to just `hg up otherbranch`.  It is important that you do not use the --clean option to `hg up`, either directly or via an alias as that will discard your uncommitted changes.

Another option is to use one of the extensions that provides `hg shelve`.  The process would then be:

```
$ hg shelve --all
$ hg up otherbranch
$ hg unshelve
```

That will create a patch of your changes within the .hg directory, returning your working directory to a clean state, switch to the 'otherbranch', and then apply the saved patch.

Comment: I didn't know this extension, thanks, it's easier than my own answer :)

Comment: Krtek, your answer was better.  Shelve isn't shipped with Mercurial for a reason.  It has a hard time with added files, doesn't support newer features, and has a horrible workflow if the shelve doesn't cleanly apply to the new location.

Comment: @Ry4an Thanks for the info.  I have experienced the horrible workflow of shelve when it can't apply cleanly as well.  It seems like there should be an extension that provides shelve-like behavior but just does your diff/import commands behind the scenes - might even be possible with just aliases.

Comment: That extension has historically been called multiple clones.  :)  Seriously, though there's a real resistance to adding any feature that helps you not commit -- you should commit a lot, not just when a feature is done, but whenever you stand up to get more coffee.  If you have policies that prevent you from just committing (and you can't change them) then the advanced solution is to use Mercurial Queues with a patch repository (`hg qinit -c `) and commit _that_ often.  Untracked changes have no place in software.

Comment: I downvotet this answer as hg shelve once destroyed my day-work. I never use it again.

Comment: This appears not to be true.  Mercurial refuses to `hg up` because there are uncomitted changes.  (Perhaps it *was* true when the answer was posted?)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is the best solution, but you can follow these steps :

1° `hg diff --git > modifications.patch`

2° `hg update -C the_right_branch`

3° `hg patch modifications.patch`

Maybe it's better to copy modifications.patch somewhere safe, just in case.

edit: update with diff instead of export. Thanks to the commenters.

Comment: will this patch only include the uncommitted changes? The branch I am working on has a lot of differences that have already been committed in the past from the branch I meant to be on.

Comment: That shouldn't be export it should be diff.

Comment: Yeah right, export is for a given revision, not current modification of the working directory, i'll update my post.